# Git - Remove file from two branches

Tags: git, rm

I have two branches, which contain a file that has recently been added to git ignore. It is an auto-generated file. I removed it in the master branch from the cache using `git rm --cached fileName`. However, i still get the message that he file would be overwritten when I try to change to the second branch using `git checkout branchName`. How can I get both branches to ignore the file, it seems like a catch to me - in order to change branch I would have to add the file again and commit it. I don't want to use `git stash`, since there are other changes I don't want to be persisted.

Comment: Did you commit the removing of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commit your current changes and remove fileName.

Answer (score 0):

You can [cherry pick the commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) (assuming that it only contained the file removal) to your branch.

```
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```